# Load-Module equivalient in PowerShell v1

Tags: powershell

(Cross-post from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683172/load-module-equivalient-in-powershell-v1))

For reasons of script portability, I need to dynamically load snap-ins in a PowerShell script (ie. I don't want to actually install it). This is easily accomplished in PowerShell v2 with the `Load-Module` function. I need to run this particular script on a machine where I, for various reasons, do not want to install PowerShell v2, but have v1.

Is there a `Load-Module` equivalent in PowerShell v1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [import-module](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd819454.aspx)